# Does Adaptive Server Anywhere not support subqueries in the FROM clause?

Tags: sql, odbc, powerbuilder, sybase-asa

I am trying to execute an SQL query on an Adaptive Server Anywhere database.  Here it is:

```
SELECT count(*) AS s
FROM (
    SELECT column1, count(*) AS n
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY column1
    HAVING n > 1
)
```

In the subquery, I want to get all the rows that are duplicates and in the outer query I want a count of the rows that are duplicates.

But the database says that I have a syntax error whenever I use a subquery in the FROM clause.  Is this not supported?

I am executing the query in interactive SQL in Powerbuilder.  I am connected to my database using ODBC.

Comment: You should ask here: http://sqla.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont know anything about Adaptive Server, but try to add alias for the subquery in from statement, like this:

```
SELECT count(*) AS s
FROM (
    SELECT column1, count(*) AS n
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY column1
    HAVING n > 1
) result -- add this
```

MSSQL needs this to work maybe AS needs it too.

Answer (score -3):

ASA does not support "in memory" tables like this.  You will need to create a temp table and then pull your count from there.